# Address validation form API or Database on iOS?

Tags: ios, forms, web-services, validation

I'm working on an iOS app where users can purchase products and get them delivered home. Before the actual purchase, the user will have to input his delivery address in the United Kingdom.

For example, the user types in the postcode "SW1A 2AB", and a UIPicker shows up listing the possible matches such as "11 Downing St".

I would like to know if there any ressources or services online (free ideally) to do an address lookup based on a UK postcode that the user will provide on the form. Since the app will be launched in the UK only and products can only be delivered here, I don't have to worry about other kinds of address formats.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert postal code to city name, is there an API available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846466/how-to-convert-postal-code-to-city-name-is-there-an-api-available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are after Postcode to Address lookup which within the UK involves using the Royal Mail Postcode Address File (PAF) which comes with a cost, however is the most reliable source for UK address data. It can be bought as a data file directly from Royal Mail however several APIs also exist, meaning you don't need to worry about storing and updating over 29 million addresses.

I work for [Allies Computing who provide a cloud hosted REST based API](https://www.alliescomputing.com/postcoder/address-lookup), which uses Royal Mail's daily updates and can be paid for on a per search basis.

Of course other providers exist offering very similar APIs, [Royal Mail's Powered by PAF website](http://www.poweredbypaf.com/) has a full list of them.

So long as your application will have access to the internet you can make use of these, although it would be a good idea to present users with a full address form if they don't have internet connection.

Comment: @Broco Great to hear.